# How to make windows read all .dll files while scanning the c: drive

Tags: c#, file

I am trying to make file scanner that scans for dlls. I try to scan my C: Drive but it doesn't scan the whole thing it just scans the portion with some random .txt and .sys files

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace DLLScanner
{
class CheaterBeater

{
        static System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection log = new System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection();
        static void Main ()
        {
            string[] drives = System.Environment.GetLogicalDrives ();   

            foreach (string dr in drives) {
                System.IO.DriveInfo di = new System.IO.DriveInfo (dr);

                if (!di.IsReady) {
                    Console.WriteLine ("The drive {0} could not be read or processed (32 Bit System)", di.Name);
                    continue;
                }
                System.IO.DirectoryInfo rootDir = di.RootDirectory;
                WalkDirectoryTree (rootDir);
            }

            Console.WriteLine ("These are files with restricted access or could not be processed:");
            foreach (string s in log) {
                Console.WriteLine (s);
            }
            Console.WriteLine ("Press any key to exit");
            Console.ReadKey ();
        }

        static void WalkDirectoryTree (System.IO.DirectoryInfo root)
        {
            System.IO.FileInfo[] files = null;
            System.IO.DirectoryInfo[] subDirs = null;

            // First, process all the files directly under this folder
            try {
                files = root.GetFiles ("*.*");
            } catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e) {

                log.Add (e.Message);
            } catch (System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException e) {
                Console.WriteLine (e.Message);
            }

            if (files != null) {
                foreach (System.IO.FileInfo fi in files) {
                    Console.WriteLine (fi.FullName);
                }
            }

        }   }
}
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: do you like to scan the whole drive or just the root folder?

Comment: @whymatter Whole drive. I thought the root whould scan the whole drive? What would I have to do to scan the whole drive.

Comment: You should not do that. It will take long time to run and make the hard drive work uselessly as there are practically no useful reason to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like to search not only the root directory you should use an overload of the [DirectoryInfo.GetFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143327(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

You are now able to pass [System.IO.SearchOption](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143448(v=vs.110).aspx) type to the method to tell the method you want to search all subdirectories.

Finally it should look like this:

```
root.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

but if you like to search for dll files you should specify it directly like this:

```
root.GetFiles("*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

BUT as already mentioned:

> You should not do that. It will take long time to run and make the
>   hard drive work uselessly as there are practically no useful reason to
>   do that.

He is perfectly right, it a verry big operation to search through your complete hard drive. But if you dont use it in production why not :)

I dont know why people are downvoting your question...

Comment: Could you give a example of the usage of _DirectoryInfo.GetFiles_ method nad how would I use it to search the whole drtive?

Comment: whoops didn't see the hyper links!

Comment: and you havent seen my examples: root.GetFiles("*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

Comment: no i swa those but i got confused I got it now.

Comment: If its working then please close the question :)

Comment: Done! Thanks so much